# Resetting multiple drop down menus in excel using a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I currently have a workbook with 40ish questions that each have a 5 option drop down menu. I wanted to see if I could create a macro/use vba to reset all of them to "1-Completely Disagree".
[image]

Tried:

```
Sub Reset_Dropdowns() 
Range("C3:C55").Value = "Completely Disagree" 
End Sub
```

Comment: You can definitely do that. Please post what you've come up with so far so we can assist.

Comment: Hey, thank you for the response. I am new to vba, so still getting the hang of it. So far I have tried this, but it only writes text below the drop down menus. It doesnt actually reset anything.

Comment: Sub Reset_Dropdowns()
    Range("C3:C55").Value = "Completely Disagree"
End Sub

Comment: `code`

Option Explicit

Sub ResetDataVal()
    Sheets("Individual Allocation").Range("C3:C55").Value = "Completely Disagree"
End Sub

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you're code is faltering is that you are attempting to update an entire range at once which isn't possible. Reference each cell individually like so:

```
Sub Reset_Dropdowns() 
  Sheets("Control").Range("C4").Value = "Completely Disagree" 
  Sheets("Control").Range("C8").Value = "Completely Disagree" 
  Sheets("Control").Range("C12").Value = "Completely Disagree"
  ' etc
End sub
```

I've assumed the cell references, but that should get you on your way!

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I am running into the same issue again and again with this now, where when I input this type of code, it merely types the answers behind the drop down menus instead of changing them. It's like the drop down is floating. When I got to format the menu it is listed as "Control$C$4"

Comment: Glad I could help :)